# Map through null exception when i try to get values on another map base on key

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, trigger, javascript, css

here I'm facing one issue bcoz of the map I did try but it's not solved here try to get value in the map based on the key, but in some case key not available then it shows me the exception  . this line
`if(woMeasMap.get(ipMeas.Id)[0] != null)`

```java
@AuraEnabled                                                              
    public Static Map<String,Map<String,List<wrapperClass>>> getSelectedVlaues(String ipMachine, String measurementType, Date selectDate, Date endDates, string selectType, String currentId )
    {
        
        wrapperClass returnWrapperValue = new WrapperClass();
        
        System.debug('End Date'+selectDate);
        System.debug('start Date'+endDates);
        System.debug('selectType'+selectType);
        List<String> ip = (List<String>)JSON.deserialize(ipMachine, List<String>.class);
         System.debug('install product'+ip);
        List<String> Measurement = (List<String>)JSON.deserialize(measurementType, List<String>.class);
        // System.debug('measurement type'+Measurement);
        List<SVMXC__Installed_Product__c> ipName = new List<SVMXC__Installed_Product__c>();
        
        Map<String,Integer> rank = new Map<String,Integer>();
        List<ID> tempaccid=new List<id>();
        if(ip.isempty())
        {
            ipName = ([Select Name, Id, Current_Reference_Name__c From SVMXC__Installed_Product__c Where SVMXC__Company__c =: currentId]);
        }
        else
        {
            ipName =([Select Name, Id, Current_Reference_Name__c From SVMXC__Installed_Product__c Where Current_Reference_Name__c IN:ip ]);
            System.debug('ipname '+ipName);
        }
        System.debug('Measurement'+Measurement);
        Integer value;
        
        List<IP_Measurement__c> ipMeasurement = new List<IP_Measurement__c>();
        
        if(Measurement.isempty())
        {
            List <SVMXC__Installed_Product__c> ipMach = [Select Name,ID From SVMXC__Installed_Product__c Where SVMXC__Company__c =: CurrentId];
            for(SVMXC__Installed_Product__c i :ipMach )
            {
                tempaccid.add(i.ID);
            }
            
            ipMeasurement = ([select Name, ID, Unit__c, Template__r.Installed_Product__c from IP_Measurement__c Where Template__r.Installed_Product__c IN :tempaccid]);
        }
        else
        {
            ipMeasurement = ([select Name, ID, Unit__c, Template__r.Installed_Product__c from IP_Measurement__c Where Name IN:Measurement]);
            
        }
        system.debug('full list'+ipMeasurement);
        
        Map<id,List<IP_Measurement__c>> ipMeasMap = new Map<id,List<IP_Measurement__c>>();
        
        for(IP_Measurement__c ipMeas : ipMeasurement){
            if(ipMeasMap.containsKey(ipMeas.Template__r.Installed_Product__c)){
                List<IP_Measurement__c> ipMeasurementList = ipMeasMap.get(ipMeas.Template__r.Installed_Product__c);
                ipMeasurementList.add(ipMeas) ;  
                ipMeasMap.put(ipMeas.Template__r.Installed_Product__c, ipMeasurementList);
            }else{
                ipMeasMap.put(ipMeas.Template__r.Installed_Product__c, new List<IP_Measurement__c>{ipMeas});
            }
        }
        
        List<IP_Measurement__c> ipMeasLists = new List<IP_Measurement__c>();
        
        // for Work Order measurement 
        List<WO_Measurement__c> workorder = new List<WO_Measurement__c>();
        
        
        if(selectType.contains('THIS_MONTH'))
        {
            System.debug('This month printed');
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, IP_Measurement__c, Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c,  Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate From WO_Measurement__c  Where (CreatedDate = THIS_MONTH)order by createdDate DESC ]);
        }else if(selectType.contains('LAST_MONTH'))
        {
            System.debug('last month printed');
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, IP_Measurement__c, Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c,  Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate From WO_Measurement__c  Where (CreatedDate = LAST_MONTH)     order by createdDate DESC ]);
            
        }else if(selectType.contains('THIS_YEAR'))
        {
            System.debug('Tihs year');
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, IP_Measurement__c, Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c,  Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate From WO_Measurement__c  Where (CreatedDate = THIS_YEAR)order by createdDate DESC ]);
            
        }else if(selectType.contains('THIS_QUARTER'))
        {
            System.debug('this quarter printed');
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, IP_Measurement__c, Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c,  Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate From WO_Measurement__c  Where (CreatedDate = THIS_QUARTER)order by createdDate DESC ]);
            
        }else if(selectType.contains('LAST_QUARTER'))
        {
            System.debug('last quarter printed');
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, IP_Measurement__c, Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c,  Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate From WO_Measurement__c  Where(CreatedDate = LAST_QUARTER)order by createdDate DESC ]);
            
        }else if(selectType.contains('LAST_WEEK'))
        {
            System.debug('LAST_WEEK printed');
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, IP_Measurement__c, Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c,  Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate From WO_Measurement__c  Where (CreatedDate = LAST_WEEK)order by createdDate DESC ]);
            
        }else if(selectType.contains('THIS_WEEK'))
        {
            System.debug('THIS_WEEK printed');
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, IP_Measurement__c, Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c,  Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate From WO_Measurement__c  Where (CreatedDate = THIS_WEEK)order by createdDate DESC ]);
            
        }else if(selectType.contains('LAST_YEAR'))
        {
            System.debug('LAST_YEAR printed');
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, IP_Measurement__c, Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c,  Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate From WO_Measurement__c  Where (CreatedDate = LAST_YEAR)order by createdDate DESC ]);
            
        }else if(selectType.contains('LAST_FISCAL_YEAR'))
        {
            System.debug('LAST_FISCAL_YEAR printed');
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, IP_Measurement__c, Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c, Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate From WO_Measurement__c  Where (CreatedDate = LAST_FISCAL_YEAR)order by createdDate DESC ]);
            
        }else if(selectType.contains('THIS_FISCAL_YEAR'))
        {
            System.debug('THIS_FISCAL_YEAR printed');
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, IP_Measurement__c, Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c,  Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate From WO_Measurement__c  Where (CreatedDate = THIS_FISCAL_YEAR)order by createdDate DESC ]);
            
        }else if(selectType.contains('YTD'))
        {
            System.debug('YTD printed');
            Date ytd = Date.newInstance(System.today().year(), 1, 1);
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, IP_Measurement__c, Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c, Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate From WO_Measurement__c  Where (CreatedDate >= :ytd and CreatedDate <= TODAY)order by createdDate DESC ]);
            
        }else if(selectDate != null && endDates != null)
        { 
            System.debug('custome printed');
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, IP_Measurement__c , Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c, Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate From WO_Measurement__c where CreatedDate >:selectDate And CreatedDate <:endDates order by CreatedDate DESC]);
            
        }else
        {
            System.debug('default printed');
            workorder =([Select Name, Id, Work_Order__r.Name, Work_Order__c, IP_Measurement__c, Value__c, Unit__c, createdDate  From WO_Measurement__c order by createdDate DESC]);
            
        }
        
        system.debug('Selected Work Order :- '+workorder);
        List <String> checkWOM = new List <string>();
        Map<id,List<WO_Measurement__c>> woMeasMap = new Map<id,List<WO_Measurement__c>>();
        Map<string,String> uniqeMeas = new Map<String,string>();
        set<String> uniqyType = new set<String>();
        List<String> woMeasId = new List<String>();
        List<string> unitList =  new List<String>();
        List<String> WoName = new List<String>();
        List<String> workOrderName = new List<String>();
        List<String> workOrderId = new List<String>();
        Map<Integer,string> dateValueMap = new Map<Integer,string>();
        
        if(workorder.size() > 0 )
        {         
            system.debug('yss workorder is not empty');
            
            for(WO_Measurement__c woMeas : workorder){
                if(woMeas.Value__c >=1 &&woMeas.Value__c != null){
                    
                    system.debug('inner ids'+woMeas.IP_Measurement__c);
                    checkWOM.add(woMeas.IP_Measurement__c);
                    
                if(woMeasMap.containsKey(woMeas.IP_Measurement__c)){
                    List<WO_Measurement__c> woMeasurementList = woMeasMap.get(woMeas.IP_Measurement__c);
                    woMeasurementList.add(woMeas) ;  
                    woMeasMap.put(woMeas.IP_Measurement__c, woMeasurementList);
                }else{
                    woMeasMap.put(woMeas.IP_Measurement__c, new List<WO_Measurement__c>{woMeas});
                }
              } 
            }
            
            List<WO_Measurement__c> workOrdereasurement = new List<WO_Measurement__c>();
            
            WO_Measurement__c wom ;
            
            // end workOrder measurement map
            
            string valTime;
            Integer val=0;
            String womName;
            DateTime dT;
            Date myDate;
            String unit;
            String WOMID;
            String WOID;
            String workName;
            for(SVMXC__Installed_Product__c names:ipName)
            {   valTime = null;
             value=0;
             womName = null;
             dT = null;
             myDate = null;
             unit = null;
             WOMID =null;
             workName = null;
             WOID = null;
          //   system.debug('IP MAchine :- '+ names.Current_Reference_Name__c+'..IP id :- '+names.Id);
             
             ipMeasLists = ipMeasMap.get(names.Id);
             
             if(ipMeasLists != null)
             {    
                system.debug('install p related:- '+ ipMeasLists);
                 for(IP_Measurement__c ipMeas : ipMeasLists)
                 { 
                             try
                             {      
                                 system.debug('ipMeasLists:- '+ ipMeas.id);
                                 if(woMeasMap.get(ipMeas.Id)[0] != null) //in this line ifvalue not get then it show exception how to resolve this
                                 {
                                     
                                     uniqeMeas.put(names.Current_Reference_Name__c,ipMeas.name);
                                     uniqyType.add(ipMeas.name);
                                     wom = woMeasMap.get(ipMeas.Id)[0];
                                     if(wom != null)
                                     {
                                         if(value < wom.Value__c)
                                         {
                                             value= (Integer)wom.Value__c;
                                             dT = wom.createdDate;
                                             valTime = dt.format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss');
                                             womName = wom.Name;
                                             unit = wom.Unit__c;
                                             WOMID =wom.Id;
                                             workName = wom.Work_Order__r.Name;
                                             WOID= wom.Work_Order__c;
        
                                         }
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                             catch(Exception e)
                             {
                                 system.debug(e);
                             }
                     
                 }
```

Comment: in this code i comment this line inside for loop , here i try to get map values in loop if(woMeasMap.get(ipMeas.Id)[0] != null)  but through exception

Comment: Try adding conditions like this - 
`if(woMeasMap.containsKey(ipMeas.Id) && woMeasMap.get(ipMeas.Id).size() > 0 && woMeasMap.get(ipMeas.Id)[0] != null)`

Comment: @Ysr Shk  - Thank you so much ...above condition work